How to port a C++ Project consisting of various subprojects to Embarcadero?
I have a console application which i have developed on a linux machine. The entire projects consists of various subprojects located in their own subfolders. The subprojects create libraries (static or dynamic) which are needed by the main program.
On my linux machine i wrote a Makefile such that make first builds all the libraries in the subfolders, and then compiles the main application and links it with all the libraries.
Now i need realize this project on Windows in Embarcadero Dev C++ 6.3.
On Embarcadero, I can handle simple projects with source code for a single executable,
but i don't know how to set up projects with a more complicated structure.
What steps do i have to take to set up a project consisting of subprojects?

You already have a perfectly functioning generic build system, why move to one that is tied to a single IDE?

Can i use make in the Windows console the same way i use it on my linux machine?

Sure. Except it's called nmake on Windows.

Can i use make in the Windows console the same way i use it on my linux machine? If you use mingw the command is the same: https://www.msys2.org/#installation

Will it create a windows executable this way? Which i can use outside of MinGW?

Yes but you probably need a few dlls to run your application depending on how you build. With that said this isn't usually an issue as you can do what most commercial software does and use an installer to properly install your application and other files it requires. I have used several from NSIS, InnoSetup, Installshield and WIX.

You'd probably get more useful info if you described specific steps you took and where you got stuck and what sort of "more complicated structure" you want. The tool you want to use should also have some tutorials for more than a single executable, maybe even answering your question.

@drecherjm a mingw installation seems to be what i could use. On msys2, for example, will libraries like zlib, crypto, hdf5, math be available?

All of those are in the package manager for example: https://packages.msys2.org/base/mingw-w64-hdf5 has packages for all 5 supported environments: https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/

I installed msys2, installed make and g++, as well as zlib ("mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib") with pacman, with no errors reported. But when i call make for my application, i get an error that zlib.h does not exist. Indeed, there is np zlib.h in /usr/include/. What steps do i have to take that zlib is found?
